# Audio Not Playing Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web based messaging system which works great on desktop, but sounds do not initiate on mobile browsers. 
The instructions are as follows:

```
var mySound = new buzz.sound( "/sounds/new_msg", {
                                        formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "aac" ]
                                    });

                                    mySound.play();
                                }, function (err) {
                                    // code to handle read error
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser does this problem occur with?

Try using this code, update us on your results:

```
function initAudio() {
    var audio = new Audio('./path/to/my/sound.mp3');
    audio.addEventListener('play', function () {
        // When the audio is ready to play, immediately pause.
        audio.pause();
        audio.removeEventListener('play', arguments.callee, false);
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Start playing audio when the user clicks anywhere on the page,
        // to force Mobile Safari to load the audio.
        document.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);
        audio.play();
    }, false);
}
```